# What does linking my Xbox live account to my EpicGames account do?

Tags: xbox-one, fortnite-battle-royale, epic-games-launcher

I recently started playing Fortnite on the PC and XBox one. I have 2 separate accounts for the games, but bought the battle pass for the Xbox one. The PC and XBox one accounts use different email addresses.

When I log into my PC account, I have an option to "Link XBox account". When I try to link my accounts I get this message:

> Your Xbox Live account has already been associated with another Epic Games account.

I am confused as to what XBox live account it is trying to get connected to, as I believe it is using the same email address. When I log into my xbox account, there is no option to link a PC account.

I have the option of unlinking my XBox account, and trying to connect it with my PC account.

Are there any downsides to this? If I have my accounts connected can I use the Battlepass on PC/Xbox? Or should I just leave the accounts separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Xbox live account should be what connects your xbox profile on the games associated with epic games that you would have on the xbox. There really is no downside to it. Your purchases should be accessible on both accounts.